# Apache Camel CXF endpoint does not register a JAX-WS Handler

Tags: jax-ws, cxf, apache-camel

I'm using Camel as a proxy between a client and a web service. The intention is to enrich the incoming SOAP request that the client sends before forwarding it to the *real* web service.

I want to register a JAX-WS (protocol) handler called *sessionJAXWSHandler* with the producer endpoint (the endpoint of the real web service) but it does not appear to pick it. If I configure the same handler on the incoming enpoint, it does register the handler; I can see the debugging. I believe the [same problem is described here](http://grokbase.com/t/camel/users/125emryhyj/handler-is-not-getting-called-when-calling-external-webservice-using-camel-cxf) but it was never solved.

**My Spring-based Camel configuration**:

CXF endpoint for handling incoming SOAP messages - the handler is registered just fine:

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="hotelAvailabilityService"
                 address="/HotelAvailabilityService"
                 serviceClass="com.booking.hotel.availability.HotelAvailability"
                 wsdlURL="wsdl/MyHotelAvailabilityProxyService.wsdl">
    <cxf:handlers>
        <ref bean="sessionJAXWSHandler"/>
    </cxf:handlers>
    <cxf:properties>
        <entry key="dataFormat" value="PAYLOAD" />
        <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="false" />
    </cxf:properties>
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

CXF endpoint for outgoing requests (I cannot see any debugging so I assume that the handler has not been registered. **There are no error messages**):

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="realHotelAvailabilityService"
                 address="https://com.company.webservice/availabilityws"
                 wsdlURL="wsdl/hotelbooking.wsdl"
                 loggingFeatureEnabled="true"
                 >
    <cxf:handlers>
        <ref bean="sessionJAXWSHandler"/>
    </cxf:handlers>
    <cxf:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="unZip"/>
    </cxf:inInterceptors>
    <cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
        <ref bean="unZip"/>
    </cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
    <cxf:properties>
        <entry key="dataFormat" value="PAYLOAD" />
        <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="false" />
    </cxf:properties>
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```